# use separate Images in Bootstrap and how to make responsive

Tags: html, responsive

I am trying to use 2 images separate in Bootstrap to make responsive. I am struggling how to fix in different media queries to set exact size of the image.When i am trying to use as a background the difficult to manage a text in the middle
Please see the attached file[Responsive image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83htb.png)

Comment: can you post your code and/or upload a fiddle?

Comment: In my opinion, I would hide these images on mobiles.

Comment: @Lee i would also hide these images on mobile, but for tablet and desktop its hard to manage images

Comment: <div class="container">
<div class="col-md-12 welcome">
<div class="welcomebox">
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting only five centuries</p>
</div></div>
<div class="footer_left_img"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/footer_left.png"></div>
<div class="footer_right_img"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/footer_right.png"></div> 
</div>

Comment: No it's not, it's no different than on mobiles, you're using media queries to hide images right?

Comment: @Lee yah i am using media queries

Comment: Here is my CSS  <code>.welcomebox{width: 80%;text-align: center;margin: 0 auto;display: block;padding: 0px;}
.welcomebox h1{font-family: 'futura medium';font-size: 35px;font-weight:600;color:#e59554;line-height:55px;}
.welcomebox p{color: #fff;font-size: 14px;line-height:24px;font-family: 'gotham light';}
.footer_left_img {position: absolute;left: 319px;bottom: -1078px;}
.footer_right_img {position: absolute;right: 298px;bottom: -1060px;float: right;}</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a while of trying to figure out what you want I think you want this:

https://jsfiddle.net/leecollingsco/pbut5h2n/1/

This sets the `welcome` div as relative, so then we place the images INSIDE This div, and can control the absolute positioning relative to the container. For example, set the left image to be 25px away from the left of the container. This makes it much more easier to use for responsive ness.

I've added the class `hidden-xs` to the left image, but couldn't find the right image because of the huge code, so you'll need to add that.

Is that what you're after?

PS You need to provide ALT tags for your images

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 welcome">
        <div class="welcomebox">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting only five centuries</p>
        </div>
        <img class="footer_left_img hidden-xs" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/footer_left.png" alt="YOU NEED AN ALT TAG" />
        <img class="footer_right_img hidden-xs" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/footer_right.png" alt="YOU NEED AN ALT TAG" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but what about in Tablet and Desktop?

Comment: What about them? What do you want to do with them? Look at the link I provided, and you'll see what happens to tablet and desktop when you use the classes. Using that table, you can use whatever classes you need to have your divs/images displayed/hidden on whatever device.

Comment: here is the link hope you you understand what i want... https://jsfiddle.net/pbut5h2n/

Comment: Just hide them, or just change your CSS settings if you want to move them around, and re-size them. PErsonally, I Would hide them though.

Comment: I can easily hide in on mobile but the problem i am facing to fix in tablet and desktop

Comment: What do you want to 'fix'? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: yes please, I sent you an image with the name of Responsive Image, and example is here https://jsfiddle.net/pbut5h2n/

Comment: Thanks @Lee... its really helped me :)